# compute the number of ordered triples.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Compute the number of order triples of positive integers $(a,b,c)$ such that $$a\le b\le c \qquad \text{ and } \qquad abc =2014^3$$
I have no clue on how to solve this type of question, please teach me how to do it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Observe that the prime number factorization of $2014$ is $$2014=2\cdot 19\cdot 53$$ and therefore $$2014^3=2^3\cdot19^3\cdot 53^3$$ Now you can (brute-force) count the ordered triples, taking in account that $1$ and $2014$ itself can also be used. For example $$a=1, b=1, c=2014$$ is also an acceptable solution.